# Use same variable multiple times within one pattern

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

I'd like to be able to use a single variable multiple times within one pattern, so that it will only match if the same value is present in all places, such as

```
list match {
  case x :: x :: xs => // recurse
}
```

which would match `List(1,1,2)` but would not match `List(1,2,1)`. But this does not compile with `error: x is already defined as value x`.

In researching this question, I found out that I can also include a guard in the case clause, so I can do

```
list match {
  case x1 :: x2 :: xs if x1==x2 => // recurse
}
```

which seems to work the same way (it does, right?). This is good, but it wouldn't look as clean if I wanted the same value in many places, like

```
list match {
  case x1::x2::x3::x4::xs if x1==x2 && x2==x3 && x3==x4 => // recurse
}
```

Is there any more elegant way I can do this?

---

A few notes: Yes, I am just learning scala, if that wasn't clear, so I'm not sure this is something I'd ever really *want* to do, but I'm just interested in what's *possible*. In that regard, I'm not really looking for a completely different solution, like `takeWhile` or `filter` or something, but more so am specifically interested in pattern matching.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Scala doesn't provide quite that much flexibility with its matches (which may be a good thing, as one has to be aware of errors arising from unintentional variable re-use).

If you have a large number of identical items, you might want to consider a nested match (but note that you won't fail out of the inner match to be completed later down the outer match, so you have to handle everything locally):

```
list match {
  case x :: rest => rest match {
    case `x` :: `x` :: `x` :: xs => println("Four of the same")
    case _ => println("Well, nonempty at least")
  }
  case _ => println("Boring, there's nothing here!")
}
```

Note the backticks which mean "we've already got this variable, check against it, don't set it!".

Alternatively, if you have specialized functionality that you use repeatedly, you can create a custom matcher:

```
object FourOf {
  def unapplySeq(xs: List[Int]): Option[(Int, List[Int])] = xs match {
    case x :: y :: z :: a :: rest if x==y && y==z && z==a => Some((x,rest))
    case _ => None
  }
}
```

and then use it whenever you need that complicated pattern:

```
list match {
  case FourOf(x,rest) => println("four of the same")
  case x :: more => println("Nonempty")
  case _ => println("Yawn")
}
```

Neither of these are quite as tidy and flexible as what you were apparently hoping for, but then again, I'm not sure flipping between assigning and testing *the same variable* in a match statement is a good way to write clear code anyway.

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't expecting something perfectly clean, but was just really interested in other options so this is perfect! I didn't know about the backtick operator at all previously.

Comment: Actually, the backtick operator means "literally what's inside" and can be used to enclose anything as a variable name, e.g. `\`def\``.  Pattern matching assigns variables that start with a lower case letter, and backtick is not a lower case letter, so it just works out that way.

Answer (score 5):

For many repeats you might use stable identifiers to do a comparison (instead of catching a value):

```
val x = list.head 
list match {
  case `x`::`x`::`x`::`x`::xs => ....
}
```

But note that this won't work on empty list (you just cannot get head of it).

Comment: For the record, I totally respect om going up against Rex.

Comment: nice answer. Are you missing a `case` though? Tried to make an edit but that work out.

Comment: @Faiz yep, I missed the `case`. Thanks for noting

Answer (score 3):

I think Rex's answer rocks.  I am a fan of `unapplySeq`.  But here's a not-so-clever-and-maybe-wasteful alternative, if your main bother is just with the sequence of `==`'s in each guard.
So in the [TMTOWTDI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There%27s_more_than_one_way_to_do_it) spirit:

```
def same[A](xs: A*) = xs forall (xs.head==)

// Then in your pattern match,

list match {
  // case x1::x2::x3::x4::xs if x1==x2 && x2==x3 && x3==x4 => // recurse
  case x1::x2::x3::x4::xs if same(x1,x2,x3,x4) => // recurse
}
```

I like Om's answer as well, so here's an adaptation:

```
 list.headOption map (x => list match { 
   case `x`::`x`::`x`::`x`::xs => //...; 
   case _ => // ... 
 }) getOrElse {
   // do what you'd have done for an empty list...
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for all the different ideas! I hadn't thought about `headOption` at all.

Comment: the middle one doesn't seem, i think you need to bind x to something or make an x val first as the other examples show

Comment: Your right. Which means, unfortunately, no net gain in succinctness for that one....